# KILL Azure Data Factory pipeline/trigger

Tags: triggers, kill-process, azure-data-factory

I have created few pipelines with concurrency set to 1 and triggered them using schedule triggers. But if the pipeline doesn't get completed execution within the expected time, the next in-run triggers are queued up. In this scenario how can I KILL a trigger or the pipeline? Even if I manually canceled the execution the trigger/pipeline still consumes additional time to get canceled. Is there any method available in ADF to directly KILL the Process?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a scheduled trigger that will queue the next pipeline if the current pipeline is still running. And you want to know how to kill the currently running pipeline? or the queued pipeline?

Comment: @TrentTamura Yes I am looking to kill the current running pipeline.

Comment: Then you would need to extend the Concurrency from 1 to 2 at least, and use the Answer I posted to rather Cancel the Pipeline Run of the already running pipeline, rather than failing the new pipeline. I can edit my answer to show the pieces of code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I offer two solutions both require the concurrency limit to be > 1 (cannot queue the same pipeline or will not work):

1. Figure out if the pipeline being triggered is already running. If it is, then allow the already running pipeline to continue and kill the new one.
2. Figure out if the pipeline triggered is already running. If it is, then kill the old one and allow the new one to continue. (the reverse of the first option)

**HERE IS OPTION 1:**

To figure out if the pipeline being triggered is currently running you can use the queryPipelineRuns ADF Rest API Post command. Here is an example of this below. The output comes back in the Json format under the "value" object. You can then filter out the current run, so that if anything comes back in a Queued or In-Progress state, you know that you shouldn't run this particular trigger.

**1st, create the web request**

[image: Get Pipelines Running or Queued]

URL:   `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{pipeline().parameters.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/@{pipeline().parameters.ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().DataFactory}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01`

Body:

```
{
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "2018-06-16T00:36:44.3345758Z",
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "@{utcnow()}",
  "filters": [

{
    "operand":"PipelineName",
    "operator":"Equals",
    "values":[
        "@{pipeline().parameters.PipelineName}"
        ]
    },
{
    "operand":"Status",
    "operator":"In",
    "values":[
        "InProgress",
"Queued"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**2nd, Filter the Output of the Web Request to anything that is not your current Pipeline running using the runId of the pipeline**

[image: Web Request Output Filter]

**3rd, Use an IF Activity to determine if the FilteredItemCount is greater than zero, if it is then force fail the pipeline**

FYI, you can use a stored procedure to create a custom error message and force an error, but in my example I just divided by zero when setting a placeholder variable value.

[image: If Activity to Force Error if Pipeline running already]

**4th, after the If Activity this is really where you put whatever your pipeline actually needs to do, in my case I just used a wait activity**

[image: Where your Pipeline really starts]

I tested this and it works.

**HERE IS OPTION 2:**

In order to cancel the pipeline that is already in progress. You can start with the **3rd step** from above and instead of forcing the failure of the current pipeline, instead use the RunID from the other pipelines that are already in progress to Cancel those pipelines. After that command is completed you can continue on with your pipeline running. Remember, this method will still need concurrent runs to be at 2 or more.